# .NET Core - Download or read a Json file contents from Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: c#, azure, ubuntu, .net-core, virtual-machine

I have a node.js script on my Ubuntu VM, which produces a Json file once it finishes execution. So far I am able to execute this script from a .NET Core console app (using Visual Studio 2019) with the following code:

```
string subscriptionId = "mySubscriptionId";
string clientId = "myclientId";
string tenantId = "myTenantId";
string clientSecret = "myClientSecret";

var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
var vm = await azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroupAsync("MyAzureRg", "MyUbuntuVm");

string cmd1 = "#!/bin/bash";
string cmd2 = "cd /home/Username/myapp/";
string cmd3 = "xvfb-run nodejs myNodeScript.js";

List<string> commands = new List<string>{cmd1,cmd2,cmd3};

Console.WriteLine("Executing shell script");

await vm.RunShellScriptAsync(commands, null);

Console.WriteLine("Script executed!");
```

I then use PuTTY and SSH to the Ubuntu VM, and can confirm that the Json is properly created in path */home/Username/myapp/*. However, my question is how do I get the contents from it back (either read or download) to .NET Core app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the json file value in this scenario should be using `RunShellScriptAsync()` again, pls try the code below :

```
List<string> commands = new List<string> { "cat <your json file path>" };

var result = vm.RunShellScriptAsync(commands, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var message = result.Value[0].Message;

Console.WriteLine(result.Value[0].DisplayStatus);

var stdout = message.Substring(message.IndexOf("[stdout]") + 9).Replace("[stderr]","").Trim();

Console.WriteLine(stdout);
```

Result on my side :

[image]

Hope it helps .